# remote control a Mac from different network

Tags: ssh, vnc, remote

I'm trying to connect two Macs that are not in the same Wi-Fi network. I'd like to use terminal instead of available Remote Desktop programs.

My remote Mac had already all the preferences active in "sharing" prefs. Problem is... while I can do that from the same network using

open vnc://name.IpAddress
But I have no idea how to do that from different networks. I'd like to be able not only to enter the remote Mac, but also see the screen.

I do have full control over the hardware and software from beginning to end. The Mac will never have a monitor attached and runs my scripts and my software only. I buy the hardware, install my software, and ship. I am able to have the machine connect to their Wi-Fi so that I have all the system info needed uploaded to the database. Like local IP address... and basically everything I tell the script to do.

How can I remotely connect to the Mac from a different network ?

Comment: Are these Macs on different internet connections? Have you set up port fowarding on your routers? Have you tried the public IP of the remote machine?

Comment: Hi, Burgi, and thanks for your reply. Macs will be on different locations that I cannot foresee, so networks will differ. Also, I won't be able to acecss remote routers config.

Comment: I can get their public IP though

Comment: I don't see a solution to this without access to the routers.